# React + Socket.io: useState in socket.on causing exponential amounts of duplicate calls

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I am writing a bingo app that relies on socket.io to provide the next ball to a caller and board client. I call the server from my client using a button onClick event, which calls the following: `socket.on('get-ball', (ball) => { console.log(ball) })`

When I click the button, I see 2 log entries for each new ball the server returns (I'm assuming this is because of strict mode). Everything works fine. I click the button, a new ball is logged:

```
[Log] N39 (bundle.js, line 384, x2)
[Log] O72 (bundle.js, line 384, x2)
[Log] O69 (bundle.js, line 384, x2)
[Log] N44 (bundle.js, line 384, x2)
[Log] B9 (bundle.js, line 384, x2)
[Log] B15 (bundle.js, line 384, x2)
```

However... I also want to save each new ball into an array so that the entire list of balls get rendered when updated. To do this, I added a state var: `const [balls, setBalls] = useState([])`.

Then I try to add the new ball returned by the server to the state var in the socket.on handler by spreading the current array and adding the new value:

```
socket.on('get-ball', (ball) => {
   console.log("ball: ", ball)
   setBalls( updated => [...updated, ball])
})
```

Now each time I press the button, I notice the more balls I fetch, the longer it takes to add them. Adding some console.logs in the handler shows an ever-increasing number of logs for each. By the 8th ball, there are 1400+ log entries for that ball. The log window looks like this:

```
[Log] B11 (bundle.js, line 384, x2)
[Log] G57 (bundle.js, line 384, x6)
[Log] G50 (bundle.js, line 384, x18)
[Log] G47 (bundle.js, line 384, x54)
[Log] I22 (bundle.js, line 384, x162)
[Log] I24 (bundle.js, line 384, x486)
[Log] G54 (bundle.js, line 384, x1458)
```

When I log the balls array instead, increasing multiples of the new ball are being added to the array (in this run, the balls returned are G58, B2, B4, G46):

```
[Log] [] (0) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] [] (0) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] [] (0) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] [] (0) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] [] (0) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] [] (0) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58"] (1) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58"] (1) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58"] (1) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58"] (1) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58"] (1) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58"] (1) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58"] (1) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58"] (1) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58", "B2"] (2) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58", "B2"] (2) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58", "B2"] (2) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58", "B2"] (2) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58", "B2", "B2"] (3) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58", "B2", "B2"] (3) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58", "B2", "B2"] (3) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58", "B2", "B2"] (3) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58", "B2", "B2", "B2"] (4) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58", "B2", "B2", "B2"] (4) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58", "B2", "B2", "B2"] (4) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58", "B2", "B2", "B2"] (4) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2"] (5) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2"] (5) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2"] (5) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2"] (5) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2"] (6) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2"] (6) (bundle.js, line 387)
[Log] ["G58", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2"] (6) (bundle.js, line 387)
~clip~
```

On the server side I have a console.log to show when the client requests a ball. That log looks sane:

```
Caller requested ball
Sent ball  B11
Caller requested ball
Sent ball  G57
Caller requested ball
Sent ball  G50
Caller requested ball
Sent ball  G47
Caller requested ball
Sent ball  I22
Caller requested ball
Sent ball  I24
Caller requested ball
Sent ball  G54
```

No matter what trick I try, I keep getting growing duplicates in the balls array (another attempt was `setBalls(balls.concat(ball))`. Is there a different way I should be adding the return values from the socket call into the state array?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by moving state update to callback in the socket.emit call to retrieve ball from server....

```
// Request a ball, then add the new ball to the balls array
    const RequestNextBall = () => {
        socket.emit('get-ball', data => {
            setBalls(balls.concat(data))
        })
    }
```